# Parsing special strings within a text (eg. "%var%")?

Tags: javascript

I am supplying a Javascript function strings with commands (*SVG path commands*):

```
eg. "move 10 10 line 50 50"
```

**move and line** are ***commands***

**numbers** are ***x, y coordinates***

I would like to add **special strings** to these commands, that would instruct the function to use specific variables

```
eg. "move %mouseX%+1 %mouseY%+1"
```

where **%mouseX% and %mouseY%** would be the mouse ***x,y coordinates***

How can I parse and replace these?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this type of string manipulation, as a starting point, you could take advantage of using a powerful feature of the `String.prototype.replace` function, using its callback function:

```
function replaceTokens(str, replacement) {
  return str.replace(/\%([^%]+)\%/g, function (string, match) {
    return replacement[match];
  });
}

replaceTokens("move %mouseX%+1 %mouseY%+1", {mouseX: 100, mouseY: 200});
// returns  "move 100+1 200+1"
replaceTokens("%foo% %bar%!!!", {foo: 'Hello', bar: 'World'});
// returns Hello World!!!
replaceTokens("I'm %name%, and I %action% %place%", {name: 'CMS',
  action: 'love',
  place:'StackOverflow'
}); // "I'm CMS, and I love StackOverflow"
```

That is only a simple example about the sort of things that you are able to do with this technique. This small function will make you able to do multiple *%token%* replacements in one step.

Recommended article:

- [Search and Don't Replace](http://ejohn.org/blog/search-and-dont-replace/)

Answer (score 3):

```
var command = 'move %mouseX%+1 %mouseY%+1';
command = command.replace('%mouseX%', mouseX).replace('%mouseY%', mouseY);
```

Where mouseX and mouseY are the variables holding the mouse position.

Comment: Glad it helps. If you don't want to hard-code the special variable names and think you could add more, CMS's answer is perfect for that.

Comment: btw there is a problem, it only replaces the first occurrence!

Comment: I found out that by writing it as /%mouseX%/g makes it work properly

Answer (score 2):

You can use split method to split the string.

```
var arrSplitString = stringToSplit.split(' ');
```

and result will be an array. Then replace the corresponding index values with the desired one.

See [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/Split)

To get the mouse position you can use `e.PageX` and `e.PageY`

See [Mouse position](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Mouse_Position)